# Javafx Bar chart size

Tags: javafx-2

I want to add the data to the chart after the chart has been added to the scene. Because of that order, the animation of the rising bars is available:

```
answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Series<String, Number> aSeries = new Series<String, Number>();
aSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mytest", 120));
answer.addAll(aSeries);

chartFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));
chart.setData(answer);
```

The only problem I have is, that the bars do not use the full available space in the chart.

I tried to add the bars with yValue=1 to register the bars and after that I added the chart to the scene and updated the values. But then there is again no animation:

```
answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Series<String, Number> aSeries = new Series<String, Number>();
aSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mytest", 1));
answer.addAll(aSeries);

chart.setData(answer);
chartFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));

new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(
    Duration.millis(500),
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        answer.get(0).getData().get(0).setYValue(120);


     }
    })).play();
```

So, how can the bars use the full space but with animation?

Comment: Grab a copy of [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and analyze the chart padding with it, then, using that knowledge, apply a css stylesheet to remove the unwanted padding.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try it, but the problem is, that I need a dynamic bar Chart, so I do not want to use a css. Even the bar color I do dynamic with setStyle.

Comment: Just to clarify your problem: Do you have a fixed margin that you would like to get rid of, or do the bars actually only fill a random portion, say 50% of the chart (that is: do the axes scale incorrectly)?

Comment: The bars fill a random portion. So the the axes do not scale properly.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. Next thing I'd like to ask about the problem is: If you resize the window (or cause the chart to resize by some other mechanism), will the axes rescale properly? You might have to slow down the time line to check this.